# How to use dependency injection in FastAPI properly?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, annotations, fastapi, python-typing

I am new to FastAPI, and I'm trying to use a simple dependency injection via `Depends` with the FastAPI.

Can somebody tell me what is differences between these two code snippets for using `Depends` to have **Shared Logic**?

### 1:

```py
from typing import Annotated
from uuid import UUID
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends

router = APIRouter()

async def test_injection(id: UUID) -> str:
    return str(id)

@router.get("/", response_model=str)
async def get_root(uuid: Annotated[UUID, Depends(test_injection)]) -> str:
    return uuid
```

### 2:

```py
async def test_injection(id: UUID) -> str:
    return str(id)

@router.get("/", response_model=str)
async def get_root(uuid: UUID = Depends(test_injection)) -> str:
    return uuid
```

The idea for the first code snippet comes from FastAPI dependency injection [document](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#create-a-dependency-or-dependable), and the second idea comes from the most examples across the Internet to use `get_db` method as a dependency injection.

Comment: See the [Dependency Injection tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#declare-the-dependency-in-the-dependant), first way allows you [to share common dependencies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#share-annotated-dependencies).

Comment: They're just from different times - the Annotated typing feature wasn't introduced until Python 3.9 in PEP-0593: https://peps.python.org/pep-0593/ - before this the syntax shown in 2 was the one used in the FastAPI documentation as well.

Comment: Apart from the `Annotated` syntax which is new, your second code snippet doesn't work properly as you are trying to pass a converted UUID to `str` to a UUID hinting type which leads to an error. So in your case, it seems that just the first approach works for you.